# Deploy the project in heroku with github

Tags: heroku

I tried to launch my project in heroku, from my github repository, it seems that everything is going well but when I open the link, it does not work...

[image]

Everything looks good up there, butThen...

[image]

This is driving me crazy, I'd appreciate your help please, thank you for your time.

This is the error shown to me by the heroku logs --tail command

```
2020-06-26T16:52:31.791742+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:52:31.791742+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:52:31.899056+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:52:31.899056+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:56:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:56:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-26T16:56:32.107744+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:56:32.107744+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2b4b7432 by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:56:32.120048+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user 
arthuroali@gmail.com
2020-06-26T16:56:34.553115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 
`npm start`
2020-06-26T16:56:37.309132+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2020-06-26T16:56:37.317176+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-26T16:56:37.317482+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2020-06-26T16:56:37.317636+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-26T16_56_37_310Z-debug.log
2020-06-26T16:56:37.385611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Ok this is the code found in the package.json

```
{
"name": "angular-proyecto",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
"@types/multer": "^1.4.3",
"angular-file-uploader": "^6.2.7",
"angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
"@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
"@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.3",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~3.8.3"
}
}
```

And this would be my Procfile

```
web: node index.js
```

Comment: You haven't provided any code nor have you provided any logs.

Comment: What is written in the log?

Comment: It's really long, I'll edit the publication and place it.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: Heroku can't find a `start` script. Please [edit] your question and show us your `package.json` and (if you have one) your `Procfile`.

Comment: Okay, I just uploaded it, thanks for your time!

Comment: Also mofique and place the text as you said, I appreciate your recommendation

Comment: It seems from this post like one of your problems is you're serving your app the wrong way. Angular's dev server isn't for prod usage, you should *build* the app and serve the *result*.